# Is it possible to check whether a field has been set without triggering a race condition?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a struct that is shared across many goroutines, and I would like to reduce the number of times that one field on the struct is computed, if possible. Probably easier shown:

```
type Container struct {
    Items []Item
    mu    sync.RWMutex
}

(container *Container) func loadContainer() {
    if container.Items != nil { // This is detected as a race condition by go
        return 
    }
    container.mu.Lock()
    container.Items = loadItems() // Does some logic that I would like to avoid repeating
    container.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Is there a safe way to accomplish this? It's almost like I want a race condition, where I don't mind if it's written to multiple times, but the first thread to do so should prevent subsequent reads from doing so. Pretty new to go and concurrency in general.

Comment: Is there a reason the calling code needs to be responsible for this in the first place? Perhaps it would be easier to expose a constructor function `NewContainer() *container` that performs the loading before returning the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach you would have to lock first before you can check if `Items` has been set. E.g.:

```
func (container *Container) loadContainer() {
    container.mu.Lock()
    defer container.mu.Unlock()

    if container.Items != nil {
        return
    }

    container.Items = loadItems()
}
```

But [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) provides a better and faster alternative. Also it would be wise to hide the `Items` field so it cannot accidentally be referred to. An exported function should take care of initialization, and return the value, initialized once only:

```
type Container struct {
    once  sync.Once
    items []Item
}

func (container *Container) GetItems() []Item {
    container.once.Do(func() {
        container.Items = loadItems()
    })
    return container.items
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! Quick question: is there a good way to reset the once on error (assuming loadItems throws an error?)

Comment: `sync.Once` does not support reporting failure nor "reset".